# OS X - enlarge partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning

I had Mac OS X 10.7 on my hard drive. But it was getting really bloated and slow, etc - so I decided to do a clean install. I went into Disk Utility and added a new partition so that they were like this:

- Macintosh HD: 50%
- Clean Install: 50%

Then I installed Lion on the partition "Clean Install". After it was installed, etc, I backed up the old partition, "Macintosh HD", by going into Disk Utility, clicking on it, and pressing "New Image". I saved it onto an external hard drive, then I went back into Disk Utility, clicked on the hard drive, went to the partition tab, clicked on "Macintosh HD" in there, pressed the "-" button, and pressed "Apply".

But now my partition layout is like this:

[image: Partition Layout]

And I can't enlarge the partition. I can't enlarge it in the Recovery HD either. **How do I enlarge it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new partition (P1) in the remaining free space and restore the clean install partition (P2 = Clean Install) to it. Then I would set the Mac to boot from P1, delete P2 and expand P1 to cover remaining space.

Comment: @gadgetmo - I knew it would. You cannot easily move the beginning of a partition, but you can expand it towards the end of the disk. This trick worked because you had enough space to host the image of P2 into  P1 (since you split them equally).